# Get a subset of the keys/properties from Firebase query on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have a Firebase table with a gameplay users table called "guest". and it has a list of users with JSON keys like.

`reference.Child("guest").OrderByChild("level").LimitToLast(100);`
gets

```
  "01e3ab2017b39a3809d7ac69aedd0957": {
    "GuestUserProfileIndex": 0,
    "MappingId": "01e3ab2017b39a3809d7ac69aedd0957",
    "XP": 55395,
    "coin": 32132400,
    "first_Name": "GUEST",
    "isOnline": false,
    "isPlaying": false,
    "isRewardedVideoSpin": false,
    "lastDailyBonusTimeStamp": -8585100376467717008,
    "lastSpinTimeStamp": 0,
    "level": 12,
    "name": "Masood khan",
    "oldLevel": 12,
    "profileURL": "",
    "purchasableStriker": {
      "selectIndex": 0,
      "strikerPurchase": [
        0
      ]
    },
    "referredUser": "",
    "removeAds": false,
    "rewardedVideoSpinCount": 3,
    "timeStamp": -8584945728384719228,
    "totalLinkedReferalUser": 0,
    "totalLosserLevel": 92,
    "totalWinnerLevel": 847,
    "unlimitedFree2xSpin": false,
    "unlimitedFreeSpin": false,
    "userId": "01e3ab2017b39a3809d7ac69aedd0957",
    "winningCoin": 72828300,
    "winningCoinByReferral": 0
  },
  "03eeb04d6063f39c5c8246ffe5f97848": {
    "GuestUserProfileIndex": 9,
    "MappingId": "03eeb04d6063f39c5c8246ffe5f97848",
    "XP": 104145,
    "coin": 65512844,
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "first_Name": "GUEST",
    "isOnline": false,
    "isPlaying": false,
    "isRewardedVideoSpin": false,
    "lastDailyBonusTimeStamp": -8584959351,
    "level": 10,
    "name": "Ravi",
  }
}
```

But when want to show a leaderboard to rank users, we only want to get minimal data from that table and not all keys.

for eg just this;

```
{
  "01e3ab2017b39a3809d7ac69aedd0957": {
    "level": 12,
    "name": "Masood khan",
  },
  "03eeb04d6063f39c5c8246ffe5f97848": {
    "level": 10,
    "name": "Ravi",
  }
}
```

So we can save data transfer for unwanted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a listener to a Firebase Realtime Database node, you download all the data that exists within that node. That means that if your query returns `Guest` objects, then you read/download all the data within those nodes. You can indeed select from the `snapshot` object only the fields you are interested in, but that doesn't mean that you aren't downloading the entire node.

If you need to use the following query:

```
reference.Child("guest").OrderByChild("level").LimitToLast(100);
```

And get only the following fields:

```
{
  "01e3ab2017b39a3809d7ac69aedd0957": {
    "level": 12,
    "name": "Masood khan",
  },
  "03eeb04d6063f39c5c8246ffe5f97848": {
    "level": 10,
    "name": "Ravi",
  }
}
```

Then you should consider denormalizing the data. This means that you should copy the data that you are interested in, the `level` and the `name` fields in another node, and query that node instead of the original one. In this way, you'll only get two fields rather than 30. So you'll save a lot of bandwidth and resources.

If you're new to NoSQL databases, this might sound some kind of weird, but it's actually a quite common practice.

Comment: Hey Shrinidhi. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes this was useful, we did create a new node for this